# Build 64bit application in 32bit windows 7 OS

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2013, build, 32bit-64bit

I am on Windows 7 ultimate 32bit.
I am using VS 2013 ultimate. I have created a C# application and built it on my system. I have targeted Any CPU when build. However when i run it on 64bit systems it doesn't work. I am using external dlls such as bass.dll and others.

Here is my application: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xyf8rx6wisg7xlx/iBlock%20v1.1.2.rar?dl=0

A little research i did said about the Any CPU target. Nothing else.
I think the problem is that I am using external dlls but since they are included in I can not think of another problem.

Comment: Change the setting to either x86 if that doesn't work select x64 x86 should work

Comment: That probably means that your DLLs are 32-bit.

Comment: @MethodMan i tried both. Didnt work...

Comment: @SLaks And what can i do in that case?

Answer (score 4):

This would happen if one of your DLLs is 32-bit only.

Set your target platform to x86, so that your entire application will run always on the 32-bit runtime.

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: I am using 3 dlls, bass.dll, CoreAudio.dll, and Newtonsoft.Json.dll and all three are both 32 and 64bit. On 64bit platforms they should also be copied in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ which i already did.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I don't get any expeptions. It build normally. But when run on Windows 8.1 64bit it doesn't run. It doesn't throw any expeptions. It simply doesn't run

Comment: "Doesn't run" actually means it throws an exception when it tries to start up.

Comment: It doesn't. I am testing it on windows 8.1 64bit. I have not visual studio installed there. When i run the app, it nothing happens. It doesn't start.it launches i guess but it must be crashing somewhere...

Comment: You are getting an exception somewhere.  Without knowing what that exception is, there is nothing you can do.   Try wrapping `Main()` in a `catch` block.

Comment: I am not getting any exceptions. I will try what you proposed an catch the errors if i can. I will also try uploading the program somewhere and share it here so you have a better idea what is going on.